# Why does every word vector have 300 dimensions?

Tags: vector, nlp, gensim, fasttext

Why does every word vector in spaCy, Gensim and fasttext have 300 dimensions?

I don't understand what the dimensions mean, what is it used for, nor what information is stored in the 300-dimensional vector.

Answer (score 1):

To generally understand what's happening with word-vectors, nd more generally vector-modelling of text, you should seek online intro articles & tutorials.

You can make word-vectors in any dimensionality, when you train them from large corpora of texts. 300 dimensions has been commonly used since the original research papers from Google, as they seemed to think that offered a good tradeoff of being large-enough to capture desired functionality, without being overlarge (which requires more memory, training data, and training-time). The set of 3 million word-vectors they released, that they'd trained on over 100B words of news articles (`GoogleNews` vectors), were 300-dimensions.

Gensim defaults to 100 dimensions when creating new vectors, as something more often appropriate for the somewhat smaller datasets and systems that may be used by individual developers – but supports any value you'd like. You'll sometimes see other papers/projects using word-vectors of 400, 600, or 1000 dimensions.

In a 'dense embedding' like word2vec vectors, the individual dimensions are generally *not* intepretable. Each dimension has neither a fixed nor specific meaning. Rather, most 'neighborhoods' will (in a well-trained model) have meanings that roughly map to human-describable ideas, and certain 'directions' in the high-dimensional space may also correlated with human-describable concepts.

So, words that are synonyms or otherwise-similarly-used tend to be each others' nearest-neighbors in the space, and travelling in certain directions may also lead to other words whose menaing shift in particular ways - the aspect that lets word2vec sort-of- solve analogies, as in the famous "king - man + woman = queen" semantic-arithmetic example.